Numerically stable way to compute probability between two points on a normal distribution
I want to compute the log probability between two points (x1, x2) on a normal distribution. The straightforward way is
log(CDF(x2) - CDF(x1))

but this is not numerically stable when both x1 and x2 are far from the mean. Scipy has stats.norm.logcdf, but I want the log of the difference, not a difference of logs. Is this possible?

In what way is it not numerically stable???

@copper.hat For example, when x1 and x2 are 100 and 101 standard deviations away from the mean, np.log(scipy.stats.norm.cdf(101, 0, 1) - scipy.stats.norm.cdf(100, 0, 1)) gives an error because it's evaluating to log(0).

I would describe this as an issue of precision rather than numerical stability, since there is no algorithm involved. Pedantic nitpicks out the the way, there are many approximations to the normal distributions for large $x$, see, for example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/how-to-compute-the-probability-associated-with-absurdly-large-z-scores. That said, you could note that $\Phi(x+h)-\Phi(x) \approx \Phi'(x)h$ to get $\ln (\Phi(x+h)-\Phi(x) ) \approx {1 \over 2}x^2+\ln h -{1 \over 2} \ln (2 \pi)$.
